# Problem in bar plot, separating each set of data

Tags: pgfplots

I want to use a bar plot to compare some data. When I typed my code the results were not what I wanted. I want each set of bars to be separated clearly. The second point I want is the numbers are shown as I typed but int output the numbers were rounded. How can I solve these problems?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=.5cm,
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    bar width = 0.2 cm,
    symbolic x coords=        {4g,6g,8g,10g,2gamma,3gamma,4gamma,5gamma,6gamma,7gamma,0beta},
    xtick=data,
   xticklabels={$ 4_g $, $ 6_g $, $ 8_g $, $ 10_g $, $ 2_\gamma $, $ 3_\gamma     $, $ 4_\gamma $, $ 5_\gamma $, $ 6_\gamma $, $ 7_\gamma $, $ 0_\beta $},
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(4g, 2.337) (6g, 3.949) (8g, 5.815) (10g, 7.924) (2gamma, 1.830) (3gamma, 2.581) (4gamma, 4.379) (5gamma, 4.590) (6gamma, 6.983) (7gamma, 6.792) (0beta, 3.790)};

\addplot coordinates {(4g, 2.479) (6g, 4.314) (8g, 6.377) (10g, 8.624) (2gamma, 1.935) (3gamma, 2.91) (4gamma, 3.795) (5gamma, 4.682) (6gamma, 5.905) (7gamma, 6.677) (0beta, 3.776)};

\addplot coordinates {(4g, 2.350) (6g, 3.984) (8g, 5.877 ) (10g, 8.019) (2gamma, 1.837) (3gamma, 2.597) (4gamma, 4.420) (5gamma, 4.634) (6gamma, 7.063) (7gamma, 6.869) (0beta, 3.913)};

\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more data than a plot of that size can comfortably fit. In order to fit things, you may make the plot wider and also add the respective shifts. If you increase the precision, the rounding does not occur. In order to avoid the nodes to overlap that much, I rotated them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=12cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=.8cm,
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    %enlarge x limits=0.2,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    bar width = 0.2 cm,
    symbolic x coords=        {4g,6g,8g,10g,2gamma,3gamma,4gamma,5gamma,6gamma,7gamma,0beta},
    xtick=data,
   xticklabels={$ 4_g $, $ 6_g $, $ 8_g $, $ 10_g $, $ 2_\gamma $, $ 3_\gamma     $, $ 4_\gamma $, $ 5_\gamma $, $ 6_\gamma $, $ 7_\gamma $, $ 0_\beta $},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes near coords style={rotate=90,anchor=west}
    ]
\addplot+[bar shift = -0.25cm] coordinates {(4g, 2.337) (6g, 3.949) (8g, 5.815) (10g, 7.924) (2gamma, 1.830) (3gamma, 2.581) (4gamma, 4.379) (5gamma, 4.590) (6gamma, 6.983) (7gamma, 6.792) (0beta, 3.790)};

\addplot+[bar shift = -0cm] coordinates {(4g, 2.479) (6g, 4.314) (8g, 6.377) (10g, 8.624) (2gamma, 1.935) (3gamma, 2.91) (4gamma, 3.795) (5gamma, 4.682) (6gamma, 5.905) (7gamma, 6.677) (0beta, 3.776)};

\addplot+[bar shift = 0.25cm] coordinates {(4g, 2.350) (6g, 3.984) (8g, 5.877 ) (10g, 8.019) (2gamma, 1.837) (3gamma, 2.597) (4gamma, 4.420) (5gamma, 4.634) (6gamma, 7.063) (7gamma, 6.869) (0beta, 3.913)};

\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

an alternative with use of `pgfplotstable` (for exercise ...)

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{% table with diagram's data
X           Y1      Y2      Y3
$4_g$       2.337   2.479   2.350
$6_g$       3.949   4.314   3.984
$8_g$       5.815   6.377   5.877
$10_g$      7.924   8.624   8.019
$2_\gamma$  1.830   1.935   1.837
$3_\gamma$  2.581   2.91    2.597
$4_\gamma$  4.379   3.795   4.420
$5_\gamma$  4.590   4.682   4.634
$6_\gamma$  6.983   5.905   7.063
$7_\gamma$  6.792   6.677   6.869
$0_\beta$   3.790   3.776   3.913
    }\mydata

\begin{axis}[width=99mm,
ylabel=Population,
legend style={legend columns=-1,
              font=\footnotesize,
              /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2mm},
               anchor=north,
              at={(0.5,-0.1)},
              },
ybar=0.5mm,     % distance between bars (shift bar)
bar width=2mm,  % width of bars
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, rotate=90, anchor=west},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ymin=0, ymax=10,
    ytick={0,...,10},
    %
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table = {\mydata}{X},
    scale only axis,
    ]
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=1] {\mydata};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=2] {\mydata};
\addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=3] {\mydata};

\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]